# onclick, click not working? jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I'm simply trying to change a hover trigger to a click but for some reason any click function I use does not work?

This my current code that works when you hover...

**Current Script Thats Working on hover...**

```
    $showSidebar.hover(function() {
        $wrapper.stop().animate({ left: "-178px" }, 300);
        $sidebarSlider.stop().animate({ width: "452px" }, 300);
        $latestTweet.stop().animate({width: "452px", top : "-1px", backgroundColor: "#464848" }, 300);              
    }, function() {
        $wrapper.stop().animate({ left: "0" }, 300);
        $sidebarSlider.stop().animate({ width: "274px" }, 300);
        $latestTweet.stop().animate({ top : "-1px", width: "274px", backgroundColor: "#464848" }, 300);
    });
```

But see my attempts below to get it work when clicked, but weirdly nothing happens.

**My Attempt One**

```
    $showSidebar.click(function() {
        $wrapper.stop().animate({ left: "-178px" }, 300);
        $sidebarSlider.stop().animate({ width: "452px" }, 300);
        $latestTweet.stop().animate({width: "452px", top : "-1px", backgroundColor: "#464848" }, 300);              
    }, function() {
        $wrapper.stop().animate({ left: "0" }, 300);
        $sidebarSlider.stop().animate({ width: "274px" }, 300);
        $latestTweet.stop().animate({ top : "-1px", width: "274px", backgroundColor: "#464848" }, 300);
    });
```

and

**My Attempt Two**

```
    $showSidebar.on('click', function () {
        $wrapper.stop().animate({ left: "-178px" }, 300);
        $sidebarSlider.stop().animate({ width: "452px" }, 300);
        $latestTweet.stop().animate({width: "452px", top : "-1px", backgroundColor: "#464848" }, 300);              
    }, function() {
        $wrapper.stop().animate({ left: "0" }, 300);
        $sidebarSlider.stop().animate({ width: "274px" }, 300);
        $latestTweet.stop().animate({ top : "-1px", width: "274px", backgroundColor: "#464848" }, 300);
    });
```

and a couple of others but nudda...

This is my mark up...

```
<a href="#" title="More" class="button blu large" id="show-sidebar"><span>//</span> MORE</a>
```

and my var

```
$showSidebar  = $("#show-sidebar");
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Would be hugely helpful thanks!

---

**See working code, thanks @hurshagrawal**

```
$showSidebar.on('click', function () {
    if ($showSidebar.html() == '<span>//</span> CLOSE') {
        $wrapper.stop().animate({ left: "0" }, 300);
        $sidebarSlider.stop().animate({ width: "274px" }, 300);
        $latestTweet.stop().animate({ top : "-1px", width: "274px", backgroundColor: "#464848" }, 300);
    } else {
        $wrapper.stop().animate({ left: "-178px" }, 300);
        $sidebarSlider.stop().animate({ width: "452px" }, 300);
        $latestTweet.stop().animate({width: "452px", top : "-1px", backgroundColor: "#464848" }, 300);
        $showSidebar.html('<span>//</span> CLOSE');
    }
});
```

Comment: Using `Firebug` in FF do you get any javascript errors?

Comment: Why do you pass 2 parameters into `.click()`?

Comment: Nope, syntax errors, not nothing :-/

Comment: @zerkms how do you mean?

Comment: @Krister Andersson: how about second code sample?

Comment: @user801773: I mean literally what I said: why do you pass 2 parameters to `.click()` function?

Comment: @user801773 can you show the html for the `$wrapper`, `$sidebarSlider` and `$latestTweet elements

Comment: Passing two functions into the click event? Should be `.click( handler(eventObject) )` OR `.click( [eventData], handler(eventObject) )`

Comment: @zerkms, woops you were right, I missed that=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think $.click() takes 2 functions as parameters. Did you try taking the second function out? If you're trying to toggle between the two, you might have to write something with an if-else in there.

EDIT: Ah, or use .toggle().

Comment: Yep, your right, doesn't work like this, need to rewrite it a bit. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for the [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) command:

```
$showSidebar.toggle(function() {
    $wrapper.stop().animate({ left: "-178px" }, 300);
    $sidebarSlider.stop().animate({ width: "452px" }, 300);
    $latestTweet.stop().animate({width: "452px", top : "-1px", backgroundColor: "#464848" }, 300);              
}, function() {
    $wrapper.stop().animate({ left: "0" }, 300);
    $sidebarSlider.stop().animate({ width: "274px" }, 300);
    $latestTweet.stop().animate({ top : "-1px", width: "274px", backgroundColor: "#464848" }, 300);
});
```

Comment: Yeah good call... but one problem, I need to control the second alternation via another script, with toggle, if I click on the a#show-sidebar button when second alternation is run by another script, then it runs the second alternation again instead of starting at the beginning.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly; are you saying that there is another script that executes code similar to clicking the sidebar?  If that is the case, it is better to pipe that other code into actually clicking the side bar: e.g.  function SomeOtherCode() { showSidebar.trigger('click'); }.

Answer (score 0):

Try using bind(), I've found that more reliable across browsers.

http://api.jquery.com/bind/

basic usage in your case would be (untested):

```
$showSidebar.bind('click', function() {
  // do stuff
});
```

Comment: interesting, will try this out now.